Gazebo simulation pointcloud noise
I'm using ROS2 humble with Gazebo11. To simulate the 3D pointcloud, I use the package provided by this repo, it uses ray tag in gazebo to implement 3D scan. However, I found there are non existing points scanned by this, see , and 
My scene in gazebo is:

I don't know where these arc-like points come from. It seems to be the rim of the scan range but I wonder how to eliminate them. Please help me.
My lidar urdf is:
 <gazebo reference="${name}">
      <sensor type="ray" name="${name}">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <visualize>true</visualize>
        <update_rate>10</update_rate>
        <!-- This ray plgin is only for visualization. -->
        <plugin name="${name}_plugin" filename="libros2_livox.so">
            <ray>
              <scan>
                <horizontal>
                <samples>100</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>${0}</min_angle>
                <max_angle>${2*M_PI}</max_angle>
                </horizontal>
                <vertical>
                <samples>360</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>${-7.22/180*M_PI}</min_angle>
                <max_angle>${55.22/180*M_PI}</max_angle>
                </vertical>
              </scan>
              <range>
                <min>${laser_min_range}</min>
                <max>${laser_max_range}</max>
                <resolution>${resolution}</resolution>
              </range>
              <noise>
                <type>gaussian</type>
                <mean>${noise_mean}</mean>
                <stddev>${noise_stddev}</stddev>
              </noise>
            </ray>
          <visualize>false</visualize>
          <samples>${samples}</samples>
          <downsample>1</downsample>
          <csv_file_name>$(find ros2_livox_simulation)/scan_mode/mid360.csv</csv_file_name>
          <topic>${topic}</topic>
        </plugin>
      </sensor>
    </gazebo>


Welcome to Robotics, Bingchuan Wei. The points you're referencing look like the ground plane. What do you see when you look at a side view of the scan data?

You're right. From the side view I can see that these points are exactly ground plane, but I wonder why they exhibits features shown in the above image rather than concentric circles. Besides, I want to know how do we typically process these points from the ground plane if my lidar actually has a fov that detects the ground? Should I always use a filter? Thanks a lot.

In your question, I can see that you're referencing

<csv_file_name>$(find ros2_livox_simulation)/scan_mode/mid360.csv</csv_file_name>

which is available here, so I downloaded it to check out the scan pattern.
Typically, what I was expecting, is that a lidar will have a collection of fixed lasers on a rotating head. Each laser has its own "elevation angle," and when these elevation angles are revolved they create cones of various opening angles. Here are some graphics I threw together in Octave to help explain:


So, when you have a conventional lidar, where each laser is scribing a cone, and you intersect that cone with a plane, you get a parabola as a result. The only time you should expect a circle is when the axis of rotation (typically vertical axis) is normal to the plane surface.
In your case, I see the pose is set to zero (<pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>), but here is where things get a little unclear for me. Is your pose zero with respect to some socket or connection on the robot, or zero with respect to the world? But regardless, I'm assuming the intent here would be the axis of rotation to be vertical, which should be normal to a flat ground plane.
What I see in the mid360 scan pattern is NOT a conventional lidar arrangement. Here I would guess there's something like a MEMS micro-mirror array attached to a rotating head. There is a (relatively) slow rotation, but there's a very high-frequency oscillation riding on top of that low-frequency motion. Again, my guess would be the low-frequency component is a mechanically rotating scan head and the high-frequency component is a micro-mirror array attached to that scan head.
I looked at the scan pattern; as a note I think the time column for mid360 is wrong, it appears to be in integer seconds but other scan patterns seem to be in 10 microsecond intervals. Assuming that's the case, that times should be multiplied by 1e-5, I see this:

Zooming in a bit:

And then even further, plotting the individual points that are coming off as well:

When I look at elevation angles, for one they aren't constant. What I would expect to see with a conventional lidar is a collection of N horizontal lines, indicating there are N revolving lasers. What I see instead is a slow sine wave with a high-frequency wave riding on top:

Skipping to the detail view:

I don't have information about the scanner origin or axis conventions, but typically non-symmetric lidars seem to favor just above the horizon to well below the horizon, such that the bulk of the points are not pointed at the sky. I'm assuming from this then that it's setup like a spherical coordinate system, with 0 degrees of elevation pointing down, 90 at the horizon, and 180 straight up.
Given this arrangement and some math, I can plot the intersection of the scan pattern with the ground plane. I assumed the scanner is mounted with axis of rotation vertical (normal to the ground plane), 90 degrees elevation as pointing to the horizon, 0 degrees pointing down, and that the lidar is mounted 0.1 meters off the ground.
Here are some animations I made showing how the scan is happening at a per-point level. StackExchange limits how many pixels and frames I can put in a gif, so to keep it legible I have to host these images off-site.
 showing the lidar scan on a per-point basis. As shown with the plot of elevation angles, you can see it's a single beam bouncing up and down. Here beam points are in blue, with a trailing path history in fading blue dots with a red line drawing the beam path.
 showing the same thing, but I make the beam path a bit less visible and trail a longer history. Here you can see that, while it's one beam, it looks like it's four beams in the way the sampling occurs.
 showing what happens if I zoom out a bit I can turn off the beam path completely and increase the history - doing this shows what you're seeing in the question with the high point density near the robot and then a lot of parabolas further out.
I can't post a gif here because of size issues, and the scan pattern is messy if I include all the points, but as shown with the patterns above I can pick only every fourth point and that makes a bit cleaner of an image to show. This is (every fourth point of) one second of the scan pattern:

Regarding what you can do about it: That's a much harder question. If you are confident in your ability to estimate your own pose then you could do something like drop all points from -0.05 to +0.05, or you could crop to ONLY those points, plane fit, calculate a standard deviation, then drop points within +/- 3 standard deviations of the fitted plane, etc. I will say it will be difficult to distinguish small objects from noise.

Thanks a lot for your detailed and in-depth answer! It perfectly solved my problem and deepened my understanding of how these actually work. I want to use this scan to implement pointcloud registration but it seems they are too noisy for small features to be captured. Now I'm gonna try other simulation models, thanks a lot!
ps. I'm new here and I think your answer is really worthy. How shoud I give the score and follow you(Haha !).

@BingchuanWei happy to help! Nothing really to follow, the site is setup for a question-and-answer format so there's no concept of a "progression" within a topic. If you're interested in browsing you could try looking at tags but again there's no structure to the questions, just things that are new or highly rated. I would suggest continuing with your own development, try searching online for the specific questions you have, and if you can't find the answers you need then ask here or whichever other network you think fits. Welcome aboard!
